# How is Bootstrap used in VisualForce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app, bootstrap

Please tell me some of the websites for learning Bootstrap?

And how to use them in Visual Force Pages?

Is there any site where I can learn step by step.

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=bootstrap+and+visualforce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.oyecode.com/2013/05/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-with.html

Check out this video in above link.